# How to make set up a trusted user list and the user can broadcast a message to only them. I'm using Mantine UI

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, typescript

```
import { IconPencil } from '@tabler/icons-react'
import { z } from 'zod'
import { UserAvatar } from '@/component/user/UserAvatar'
import { gun, gunListen, useUser } from '@/misc/gun'

interface ChatRoomState {
  name: string
  messages: Record<string, Message>
}

interface Message {
  userUid: string
  userName: string
  content: string
  timestamp: number
}

export function ChatRoom(props: {
  id: string
}) {
  const { id: chatRoomUuid } = props
  const chatRoomSoul = `:chat-room/${chatRoomUuid}`

  const {
    uid: userUid,
    name: userName,
  } = useUser()

  const [chatRoomState, setChatRoomState] = useState<ChatRoomState>(() => ({
    name: '',
    messages: {},
  }))

  const [translated, setTranslated] = useState<Record<string, string>>({})

  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    gun.get(':chat-rooms').set(gun.get(chatRoomSoul))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    gun.get(chatRoomSoul).get('name').once((name: string | undefined) => {
      if (name === undefined) {
        gun.get(chatRoomSoul).get('name').put(`${userName}'s Chat Room`)
      }
    })

    const dispose = gunListen(gun.get(chatRoomSoul).get('name'))((data) => {
      const name = z.string().parse(data)

      setChatRoomState(prev => produce(prev, (dr) => {
        dr.name = name
      }))
    })

    return () => {
      dispose()
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const dispose = gunListen(gun.get(chatRoomSoul).get('messages').map())((data, soul) => {
      const message = z.object({
        userUid: z.string(),
        userName: z.string(),
        content: z.string(),
        timestamp: z.number(),
      }).parse(data)

      setChatRoomState(prev => produce(prev, (dr) => {
        dr.messages[soul] = message
      }))
    })

    return () => {
      dispose()
    }
  }, [])

  const enterMessageSent = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enterMessageSent.current) {
      return
    }

    enterMessageSent.current = true

    if (Object.values(chatRoomState.messages).some(message => message.userUid === userUid)) {
      return
    }

    const message: Message = {
      userUid,
      userName,
      content: `${userName} joined the chat room.`,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
    }

    gun.get(chatRoomSoul).get('messages').set(message)
  }, [chatRoomState.messages])

  const bottomRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if (inputText === '') {
      return
    }

    const message: Message = {
      userUid,
      userName,
      content: inputText,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
    }

    gun.get(chatRoomSoul).get('messages').set(message)

    setInputText('')

    bottomRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }

  return (
    <Paper shadow = 'xs' p = 'md' sx = {{ height: '100%' }}>
      <Stack sx = {{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Stack justify = 'center'>
          <Group position = 'center'>
            <Title order = {2}>
              {chatRoomState.name}
            </Title>

            <ActionIcon>
              <IconPencil />
            </ActionIcon>
          </Group>
        </Stack>

        <Divider/>

        <ScrollArea h = {1} p = 'xs' sx = {theme => ({ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: theme.colors.indigo[0], borderRadius: 16 })}>
          {Object.entries(chatRoomState.messages).sort(([_, a], [__, b]) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp).map(([soul, message]) => {
            return (
              <Group
                key = {soul}
                align = 'flex-start'
                sx = {theme => ({
                  flexDirection: message.userUid === userUid ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
                  marginBottom: theme.spacing.xs,
                })}
              >
                <UserAvatar username = {message.userName} />

                <Stack spacing = {0}>
                  {message.userUid === userUid ? null : <Text c = 'dimmed'>{message.userName}</Text>}

                  <Paper shadow = 'xs' p = 'xs' radius = 'md' sx = {{ minWidth: '3em' }}>
                    <Stack>
                      <Group>
                        <Text sx = {{ flexGrow: 1 }}>{message.content}</Text>
                      </Group>
                    </Stack>
                  </Paper>
                </Stack>
              </Group>
            )
          })}

          <Space ref = {bottomRef}/>
        </ScrollArea>

        <Group>
          <TextInput
            value = {inputText}
            onChange = {e => setInputText(e.target.value)}
            onKeyUp = {(e) => {
              if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                sendMessage()
              }
            }}
            sx = {{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          />

          <Button onClick = {() => sendMessage()}>SEND</Button>
        </Group>
      </Stack>
    </Paper>
  )
}
```

I'm creating a broadcast chatting function for a game and so far this is my above code but I don't know how to set up a trusted user list and the user can broadcast a message to only them. I'm not good with node.js or JavaScript. I tried searching P2P chatting and there were tons but I couldn't find any suitable and safe code for broadcasting messages to your trusted users. I wanted to search for it on the internet with no hope, this is my last hope, so please help me.